# Excel plot image at a point, rotated based on cell value

Tags: excel, plot

What I'm trying to do is intuitively simple, but I'm not sure how to do it in Excel. I have an aircraft flight path that I'm plotting. The aircraft has an initial heading. Right now, I plot the aircraft's initial position on the Excel plot with a little picture of the aircraft as the marker. This looks nice, but I would really like to rotate that image based on the heading.

Is there a way of dynamically rotating a marker in Excel?

If not, is there another way of dynamically rotating the image or maybe conditionally displaying an image based on a cell's value?

I'm using Excel 2010.

Comment: Create a hidden table of the rotated values, and derive the chart from  that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know if you can rotate a marker directly, but you can bypass adding the code:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Set pts = Worksheets(1).ChartObjects(1).Chart.SeriesCollection(1).Points

    For i = 1 To pts.Count
        ActiveSheet.Shapes.Range(Array("Picture 3")).Select
        Selection.ShapeRange.Rotation = Range("C" & i + 1).Value
        Selection.Copy
        ActiveSheet.ChartObjects("Chart 2").Activate
        ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(1).Select
        ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(1).Points(i).Select
        ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(1).Points(i).Paste
    Next
End Sub
```

in the Change events.
The **Picture3** it's the picture you want to rotate (inserted in the sheet). From the column C you take the rotating angle.
The macro rotate every time you change value the picture and insert that in the marker.
The code shall be put inside the Sheet that you have the chart, in the Change Event. Open VBA ALT+F11 and double click on Sheet1 (for example). Paste the code... or from combo select Worksheet on the Left and Change on the Right.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I see what you're doing and it looks right, but I'm not sure where to put the code.... I'm not that familiar with VBA in Excel (it's been a long time). Can you provide a few more details on this?

Comment: Ok - I got it to work... thanks! I inserted a picture and put this code in the Sheet1 code:  
`Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Target.Address = "$C$9" Then
        ActiveSheet.Shapes.Range(Array("Picture 1")).Select
        Selection.ShapeRange.Rotation = Range("$C$9").Value
        Selection.Copy
        ActiveSheet.ChartObjects("Chart 1").Activate
        ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(3).Select
        ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(3).Points(1).Select
        ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(3).Points(1).Paste
        Range("C9").Select
    End If
End Sub`